# Taking user input via EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on a simple hang man application as my first experience in Android dev.  I am having a little problem taking in the user's guessed word.  My current approach is for the user to enter their guess in an EditText field and then press a button that assigns it to a variable called userGuess.  Here is the relevant part:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    EditText word;
    TextView myTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_word);
    word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter_guessed);
    userGuess = word.toString();
    System.out.println(userGuess);
}
```

However, when I print its value, I am greeted with the following:

`System.out﹕ android.widget.EditText{23b92b5a VFED..CL .F...... 48,1064-213,1188 #7f080042 app:id/letter_guessed}`

I believe that my problem lies in the casting of the word and am not sure if I am taking the correct approach.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Taking+user+input+via+EditText&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=P9taVcOaO5eUuATK7oDACw) is Google search result when you type your question on Google.

Comment: While good questions remain unanswered, 7 people chose to answer this joke of a question, an obvious duplicate with a score of -8. Rep hunters are out in numbers today. Sigh ...

Answer (score 2):

Simply just do this

```
public void onClick(View view){
    EditText word;
    TextView myTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_word);
    word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter_guessed);
    userGuess = word.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(userGuess);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getText()` to retrieve text from `EditText`.

```
word.getText().toString();
```

Comment: If you see the same answer already answered....then please try to upvote it instead of repeating the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `word.getText().toString();`

Comment: If you see the same answer already answered....then please try to upvote it instead of repeating the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code :

```
public void onClick(View view){
    EditText word;
    TextView myTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_word);
    word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter_guessed);
    userGuess = word.toString();
    System.out.println(userGuess);
}
```

Try using this:

```
EditText word= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.letter_guessed);
TextView myTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_word);
String userGuess;

public void onClick(View view){

    userGuess = word.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(userGuess);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getText() is used to input from [editText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

```
userGuess = word.getText().toString().Trim();
```

Comment: If you see the same answer already answered....then please try to upvote it instead of repeating the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by little changes in your code. Try:

```
userGuess = word.getText().toString();
```

Comment: If you see the same answer already answered....then please try to upvote it instead of repeating the same answer.